# Oracle - query to retrieve CLOB value under multple tags with same name

Tags: string, oracle, clob, xmltype

I have a table T with `CLOB` column called `XML_CLOB`

Value in the column likes following:

```
<reportName>
 <string>REPORT_A</string>
 <string>REPORT_B</string>
 <string>REPORT_C</string>
</reportName>
```

I'm trying to retrieve string value from this CLOB column and return in different rows. If I use

```
xmltype(xml_clob).extract('//reportName/string/text()').getstringval()
```

it outputs like 'REPORT_AREPORT_BREPORT_C' in the same row.

I also tried 
    `extractValue(xmltype(xml_clob), '//reportName/string[1]')`
but the problem is I don't know how much child values under  tag

Is there anyway I can retrieve in different rows like:

`1 REPORT_A
2 REPORT_B
3 REPORT_C`

Many thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (xml_clob CLOB );

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 
'<reportName>
 <string>REPORT_A</string>
 <string>REPORT_B</string>
 <string>REPORT_C</string>
</reportName>'
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  x.string
FROM    table_name t,
        XMLTable('/reportName/string'
          PASSING XMLType( t.xml_clob )
          COLUMNS string VARCHAR2(50) PATH '/'
        ) x
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE( s.COLUMN_VALUE, '/string' ) AS string
FROM   table_name t,
       TABLE(
         XMLSequence(
           EXTRACT(
             XMLType( t.xml_clob ),
             '/reportName/string'
           )
         )
       ) s;
```

**Output**:

```
STRING
--------
REPORT_A
REPORT_B
REPORT_C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH test_table AS
  (SELECT xmltype('<reportName> 
<string>REPORT_A</string> 
<string>REPORT_B</string> 
<string>REPORT_C</string>
</reportName>' ) xml_clob
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT x.*
FROM test_table,
  xmltable('/reportName/string' 
  passing test_table.xml_clob 
  columns report_name VARCHAR2(100) path 'text()') x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ^ Work as expected